texstudio spellcheck not working
I am new to texlive and texstudio.
I am using texstudio 4.8.0.
I find that spell check is not working. Below is the configuration info.
What can I do to make spell check working?
By the way, I am mostly using english in my tex files.


Welcome! Have you installed any dictionaries? You need to install the dictionaries you want. I can't tell you how to do that on Windows. Does the US dictionary exist in your file system? If so, try setting the default language to US English (even if that's not what you want in the end).

@cfr   so you mean I have to download a dictionary myself?

Er, I'm not sure. Dictionaries are separate, but I wouldn't download them directly unless I needed an unusual language. But that's because Linux distros provide this kind of thing packaged. But a lot of software uses one of the standard spelling mechanisms or at least utilises dictionaries in a standard format, rather than providing their own. That seems to be what TeX Studio does: it uses dictionaries in the same format as LibreOffice and OpenOffice. LibreOffice uses hunspell under-the-hood, which is a standard spellchecker (like aspell or ispell). cont.

So I don't know how you installed TeX Studio, but you may well need to install dictionaries separately. Is there anything in the dictionaries directory it lists? Please be aware I'm not familiar with Windows or with the way software is packaged for Windows. On my system, I'd expect my editor to use a dictionary in a standard location rather than one specific to the application. But that may not be how things work on Windows. (It's possible it is a TeX Studio decision, but I'll assume it is Windows-specific until proven otherwise.)

TeX Studio also uses hunspell, so it makes sense they'd use the same dictionaries as LibreOffice. And it can use something called languagetool, apparently, but that may be for grammar. I can't think it's needed for spelling, but I'm not certain.
